# Best practice when setting up key, value table relationship

Tags: sql, database-design

I have a couple of tables in my database A, B, C, D.

I need these tables to have a information key,value map linked to them.
Set it up like this in case there should be a table E which need a set of "key,value"-information tags.

Is this a bad database design? I have a feeling in my stomach that it's not pretty.

```
Table A,B,C,D
info_group_id (reference to Info_group.id)

Table Info_group
id serial

Table Information_tag
info_group_id (reference to info_group.id),
key varchar(64),
value integer
```

Comment: I found a problem with that model. I can't have a good on delete cascade rule if I delete from table A,B,C,D. Will think I will go with a relationship table for each table.

Comment: Is the set of keys you want to store variable or is it a static set? The key and values are pertaining to the group or to the records in tables A to D ?

Comment: They are variable. info_group can have 0-n tags. The key values are pertaining to the group and the group have a reference in the A-D table. But I have seen now that I need one per table because if I delete a entry in A it does not cascade delete to info_group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your (setup) fk relationships are running in the opposite direction of the actual dependencies.

The way I would have setup a key/value or tag database would be as follows:

```
Tag
=================
id
value/information


TableA
========
id   
column1   
column2 
......


TagReferenceTableA  
====================
tableA_Id  -- fk to TableA
tag_id     -- fk to Tag
```

This allows foreign keys, and cascade-deletes to the *reference* table.  You will not be able to remove references from the tag table as part of the cascade (well, without triggers or something), and probably shouldn't.